# Display crashes

Tags: display

[image: My Display]

I'm running Ubuntu 18 in Virtual Box, I have core i7 7th generation, amd r5 430m 2gb, 8gb ram

Comment: What makes you believe it's an Ubuntu problem instead of a Host issue or vbox setting?

Comment: because other Virtual machine are working properly

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18.  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format; so you could be talking about the 2018.April (18.04 LTS) or the latest 2018.October (18.10) release. Are we to guess?

Comment: My VMs on my i7 test machine work fine and don't crash. How are yours different from mine? How can I reproduce this issue on my test equipment?